# SQL Management Studio 2012 conflicting with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, ssms

I can't seem to install both programs on my computer at the same time and I don't understand why!

Management Studio requires Visual Studio Shell Isolated 2010 to work, but if it's installed I get a 'Invalid License Data' error on VS2012.

The solution I found is to uninstall the Visual Studio Shell, but then SQL stops working.

Very annoying! Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I uninstalled both and installed VS before SQL this time. Seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, rather than reinstalling both products, I repaied the SQL Server installation, and it worked perfectly fine.

click on the MS SQL installer, and under the maintance, you will find the repair option, just click next and it will take some time to process.